# prove that if $\sum 2^na_{2^n}$ converges then $\sum a_n $ converges

Tags: proof-verification, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

Suppose $\sum a_n$ is a series with decreasing, nonnegative terms. Define $$s_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k = a_1+\cdots +a_n $$ and $$t_n = \sum _{k=0}^n 2^ka_{2^k} = a_1+2a_2+4a_4+\cdots +2^na_{2^n}.$$

Also,  $s_n$ is defined for all $n\geq 1$ whereas $t_n$ is defined for all $n\geq 0$. I have already proved that 
 $$s_{2^{n+1}-1}\leq t_n$$ for all $n\geq 0$.

**Proof**:
Since $a_n$ is decreasing then $2a_2>a_2$ and $4a_4>a_4+a_5+a_6+a_7$ so then $2^na_{2^n} > a_{2^2}+...+a_{2^{n+1}-1}$ so therefore $s_{2^{n+1}-1}$ for all $n\geq0$.

However now I need to use that proof I have found above and try and prove that if $\sum 2^na_{2^n}$ converges then $\sum a_n $ converges. Looking for some help with this second proof.

Comment: @Rafael Wagner thanks for the edit, do you know how to work through this proof?

Comment: $t_n \leqslant -a_1 + 2\bigl( a_1 + a_2 + (a_3 + a_4) + (a_5 + a_6 + a_7 + a_8) + \dotsc\bigr)$

Comment: does that prove $\sum 2^na_{2^n}$ converges then $\sum a_n $ converges

Comment: No, that's the other part of the "if and only if". For the direction you want, the inequality you already have in your question is enough. Together with something about monotonic sequences.

Comment: what do I need to say about monotonic sequences?

Comment: When is a monotonic sequence convergent?

Comment: if it is increasing and bounded above?

Comment: I am working on it cause this is a very interesting question

Comment: thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Or decreasing and bounded below. But since the sequences of partial sums are increasing here, we're interested in the first case.

Comment: okay so how do I show that?

Comment: That follows from $a_n \geqslant 0$.

Comment: @hburt the answer given below is a correct answer. Can you understand it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $s_w=\sum\limits_{n=1}^w a_m$ is a non-decreasing sequence. Take any $w$ and let $2^m> w$, then:

$s_w=\sum\limits_{n=1}^w a_n\leq \sum\limits_{n=1}^{2^m-1}a_n \leq \sum\limits_{n=1}^{m-1} a_{2^n}+a_2+\dots+ a_{2^{n+1}-1}\leq \sum\limits_{n=1}^{m-1} 2^na_{2^n}\leq \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty 2^n a_{2^n}$.
We have proved $s_n$ is non-decreasing and bounded, and hence converges.

Analogously, if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges we have:

$\frac{\sum\limits_{n=1}^w 2^n a_{2^n}}{2}\leq \sum \limits_{n=1}^w a_{2^{n-1}+1}+a_{2^{n-1}+2}+\dots a_{2^n}\leq \sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$.

So if either series converges, so does the other one.